# Binomial coefficients sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $n \geq 1$ and $N \geq 1$ be integers. I am interested in the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom{k +  n-1}{n - 1}$$ I don't know how to tackle this. I've tried using the definition of $\binom{n}{k}$ but did not get anywhere.

Could anyone suggest a method of attack for  evaluating this sum?

Comment: You can use the result of the user *drhab* below and proof e.g. by induction.

Answer (score 3):

In general we have:$$\sum_{i+j=k}\binom{i}{r}\binom{j}{s}=\binom{k+1}{r+s+1}$$

For a proof of that see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2547323/75923).

Setting $s=0$ we get:$$\sum_{i=r}^k\binom{i}{r}=\binom{k+1}{r+1}$$
which get the looks of the summation in your question.

Based on this we find:$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}=\sum_{k=n-1}^{N+n-1}\binom{k}{n-1}=\binom{N+n}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}}&=\sum_{k=0}^N[z^{n-1}](1+z)^{k+n-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=[z^{n-1}](1+z)^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^N(1+z)^{k}\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^{n-1}](1+z)^{n-1}\frac{(1+z)^{N+1}-1}{(1+z)-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^n]\left((1+z)^{N+n}-(1+z)^{n-1}\right)\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{N+n}{n}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (3) we factor out terms which do not depend on $k$.
- In (4) we use the *[finite geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (5) we collect terms and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $z^n$.